# jQuery DataTables warning: table id=oncallScheduleTable - Requested unknown parameter 'OnCallScheduleId' for row 0, column 0

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, datatables

I am facing problem while binding data to jQuery Datatable. Its throwing error message mentioned in subject.

Script

```
$("#oncallScheduleTable").DataTable({
            "processing": true, // for show progress bar
            "serverSide": true, // for process server side
            "filter": true, // this is for disable filter (search box)
            "orderMulti": false, // for disable multiple column at once
            "ajax": {
                "url": "/OnCallSchedule/LoadData",
                "type": "POST",
                "datatype": "json"
            },
            "columnDefs":
            [{
                "targets": [0],
                "visible": false,
                "searchable": false
            }],
            "columns": [
                { "data": "OnCallScheduleId", "name": "OnCallScheduleId", "autoWidth": true },
                { "data": "ClientName", "name": "ClientName", "autoWidth": true },
                { "data": "ClientProgramName", "ClientProgramName": "Address", "autoWidth": true },
                { "data": "ScheduleDate", "name": "ScheduleDate", "autoWidth": true },
                { "data": "StartTime", "name": "StartTime", "autoWidth": true },
                { "data": "EndTime", "name": "EndTime", "autoWidth": true },
                { "data": "UserRoleName", "name": "UserRoleName", "autoWidth": true },
                { "data": "ContactName", "name": "ContactName", "autoWidth": true },
                { "data": "PrimaryPhone", "name": "PrimaryPhone", "autoWidth": true },
                {
                    "render": function (data, type, full, meta)
                    { return '<a class="btn btn-info" href="/OnCallSchedule/Edit/' + full.OnCallScheduleId + '">Edit</a>'; }
                },
                {
                    data: null, render: function (data, type, row)
                    {
                        return "<a href='#' class='btn btn-danger' onclick=DeleteData('" + row.OnCallScheduleId + "'); >Delete</a>";
                    }
                },
            ]
        });
```

Data snapshot getting return from MVC action -

[image]

I am doubting with my data format logging to the console. Please take a look and let me know where i am wrong. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is solved. It was a case-sensitive issue. Data being returned in JSON was in camecase and I was not using camelcase in data value of Columns field. Thank you :)